# updating data in webpage in table with jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter as well as in jquery ajax. I have a table in the webpage where data are read from database and displayed(i.e. information about employees). I have also a dropdown on the same page where user can select from various departments. Now, what I want is, I want to display the records according to the selection made in the dropdown(i.e. according to department) on "change event". Also, I am using jquery dataTable as the page table. I visited many forums but din't find the exact solution. Any help would be appreciated. Better, if I can get codes from scratch, or even, link to the exact solution is fine.
My attempt is,
`ajax_read.php` view file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="classes"></div>

<select id="grades">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<div id='result_table' style="color:white;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#grades').change(function(){          
        $("#classes > option").remove(); 
        var grade_id = $('#grades').val();  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/index.php/ci/get_classes/"+grade_id, 
            data: {gradeid:grade_id},
            success: function(classes) 
            {
                $.each(classes,function(id,name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(id);
                    opt.text(name);
                    $('#classes').append(opt); 
                });
            }        
        });

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Welcome.php` controller file is

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->get_classes();
}
function get_classes($gradeid)
{
$this->load->model('get_db');
header('Content-type: application/json');

if ($query = $this->get_db->get_all_classes($gradeid))
{
    echo json_encode($query);
} else {
    redirect('login/loginform');
}

}
}
```

`get_db.php` model file is

```
<?php

function get_all_classes($gradeid)
{

$this->db->where('id', $gradeid);

$query = $this->db->get('info');

if($query->result()){
    $result = $query->result();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $options[$row->id] = $row->name;
    }   
    return $options;
} 
}
?>
```

There may still be some stupid errors, because I just copy pasted the codes from forum and I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: What did you try ? Some code ?

Comment: @Poria I updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console ? Try changing url   url: "localhost/index.php/ci/get_classes/"+grade_id,  to   url: "localhost/index.php/welcome/get_classes/"+grade_id,

Comment: Your ajax is being fired but I am not sure about the problem on server side until you show me some by checking console

Comment: my console shows nothing.
but this is the error I get in my screen
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: It means wrong json format is returned from the server

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: validate your json here http://jsonlint.com/